# Need to redirect the homepage to a different url but keep the site live and accessible

Tags: uri

A website built in drupal now client has come back and said the url needs to direct to another address. We want to keep the site up and working for various reasons so how do I go about doing this?

1. homepage needs to redirect to another site
2. the existing website homepage needs to be moved to a different page /main or /homepage and accessible only thru the direct link

how do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

They are many solution to redirect from the page.

1. If you are using Apache you can use **.htaccess** to redirect the front page to a different website. This would be the faster due that is on the server level. Here is more information about [redirects on Apache.](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/242/How+do+I+redirect+my+site+using+a+.htaccess+file%3F)
2. If you are using Nginix here are some [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294481/how-to-redirect-a-url-in-nginx)
3. Another option would be doing it on the theme level. If have access to the theme you can write  sites/all/themes/YOURTHEME/page.tpl.php.

   ```
   <?php
      if(drupal_is_front_page()) {
        header("location: http://www.RedirectPage.com");
        exit;
      }
   ?>
   ```
4. If you dont have access to the theme or to the server. The easiest way to have a redirect is by using the meta tag. You can add a block to the front page and add the following code.

   ```
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10; url=http://www.RedirectPage.com/">
   ```

For more information about Redirect check this [article](http://www.webweaver.nu/html-tips/web-redirection.shtml).

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way I could think to achieve this would be:

1. Create a directory inside the webroot with the name you wish your site to have `main` or `homepage`.
2. Copy the entire site inside this directory.
3. Change the value of `$base_url` in sites > default > settings.php if it is already set.
4. In the webroot create a index.php file and just enter the following code:

   ```
   <?php
   header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
   exit;
   ?>
   ```

   which will redirect the homepage of the current site to example.com

Answer (score 0):

Go to your themes folder. i.e., sites/all/themes/YOURTHEME/page.tpl.php, 
Put this on top of the page.

```
<?php
if(drupal_is_front_page()) {
header("location: http://www.google.com");
exit;
}
?>
```

Or you looking for this or any else?

Answer (score 0):

Redirect to another site using .htaccess redirect rule. About the home page to be show in another url, go and edit the node and simply change the url in the url alias.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `admin/config/system/site-information` and  set `front page address` to what you want.